# I am unable to change text in EditText1 in response to the text change in EditText2

Tags: android, android-edittext, converters, forceclose, textchanged

I want the user to enter a temperature in Celsius and display the temperature in fahrenheit and vice versa. I think TextChangedListener would be perfect to convert without any button pressing. The values go on changing as the user types in.

The biggest problem I'm having is that the EditText won't take any input. The moment I input anything, the app force closes. Please tell me what's wrong.Here's my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText C, F;
Button exit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    C = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.celsius);
    F = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fahrenheit);
    exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);

    C.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        float f,c;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            c = Float.parseFloat(s.toString());
            f = (((9 / 5) * c) + 32);
            F.setText((int) f);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    F.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        float f
                ,
                c;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            f = Float.parseFloat(s.toString());
            c = ((f - 32) * (5 / 9));
            C.setText((int) c);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

Here's my Logcat.

```
01-25 00:55:35.486    7051-7051/com.jainchiranjeev.mylearning7.mylearning_7 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jainchiranjeev.mylearning7.mylearning_7, PID: 7051
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getChars(SpannableStringBuilder.java:915)
        at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:81)
        at android.text.method.ReplacementTransformationMethod$ReplacementCharSequence.getChars(ReplacementTransformationMethod.java:151)
        at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:81)
        at android.text.TextUtils.indexOf(TextUtils.java:114)
        at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:187)
        at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:288)
        at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:174)
        at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:6205)
        at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6103)
        at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6752)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3850)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3708)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:81)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3683)
        at com.jainchiranjeev.mylearning7.mylearning_7.MainActivity$2.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:66)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7610)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3853)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3708)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:81)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3683)
        at com.jainchiranjeev.mylearning7.mylearning_7.MainActivity$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7610)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3853)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3708)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:81)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3683)
        at com.jainchiranjeev.mylearning7.mylearning_7.MainActivity$2.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:66)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7610)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3853)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3708)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:81)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3683)
        at com.jainchiranjeev.mylearning7.mylearning_7.MainActivity$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7610)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3853)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3708)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:81)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3683)
        at com.jainchiranjeev.mylearning7.mylearning_7.MainActivity$2.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:66)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7610)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3853)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3708)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:81)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3683)
        at com.jainchiranjeev.mylearning7.mylearning_7.MainActivity$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7610)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3853)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3708)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:81)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3683)
        at com.jainchiranjeev.mylearning7.mylearning_7.MainActivity$2.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:66)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7610)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3853)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3708)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:81)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3683)
        at com.jainchiranjeev.mylearning7.mylearning_7.MainActivity$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7610)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3853)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(
```

Comment: "app force closes" likely means error, so error logcat would be nice to debug

Comment: kindly post your logcat.

Comment: there are 2 places where i think error can come 
#1. f = Float.parseFloat(s.toString());
#2.  C.setText((int) c);

for the former make sure only number is given as string for debugging supply a value explicitly like f = Float.parseFloat("35");  and second dont use (int) casting afaik edittext accepts only text and string rather for debugging just  print like this "The Value is : "+c ( this is for debugging)

Comment: TextView worked out well as some kind people pointed out. But do you know of a way I can implement this in an EditText.? I am actually working on a Number converter app (Binary, Octal, Hex and Decimal). I am having multiple EditTexts in it. And I want user to enter any number and get others. I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement two `TextViews` to display the result of each calculation. What you are doing now is creating an infinite loop, when changing text in the first `EditText` trigger your second edit texts `onTextChanged` listener, and so on. Hence the stackoverflow error.

Change your implementation to display each `EditText` calculation in a `TextView`, then the problem will be gone.

In short, add your `TextView`

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

and in your

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    c = Float.parseFloat(s.toString());
    f = (((9 / 5) * c) + 32);
    tv .setText(String.valueOf(f));
}
```

Comment: The problem still persists. I simple cannot enter any text. Converting the unit is a later thing. I have posted my logcat if that helps.

Comment: @ChiranjeevJain. Ah, I did not see the last part of your code. This is simply a logic problem. You have two EditTexts with a onTextChange listerner. If you edit text in the first, you add text in the second. But then you tell the second to change your text in the first. It will be an infinite loop, hence the stackoverflow error. You need to review your logic.

Comment: That worked out well. Thanks for the help. But do you know of a way I can implement this in an EditText.? I am actually working on a Number converter app (Binary, Octal, Hex and Decimal). I am having multiple EditTexts in it. And I want user to enter any number and get others. I hope you understand my question.

Comment: @Chiranjeev Jain you should create a separate question for that. If this answer solved your current question, please tick if as the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

try that code

i have just studied the documentation and it says that

**onTextChanged() is not a place to modify text of EditText**

here is the link for documentation you can verify from there

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

so wahat you can do is to move the code to after text change.

```
C.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    float f
            ,
            c;

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {



    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (!isAlpha(s.toString)){

            if(!s.toString().equals("")){

                c = Float.parseFloat(s.toString());
                f = (((9 / 5) * c) + 32);
                F.setText(""+ f);
             }
        }
    }
});
```

this isAlpha function is to check whether user entered numeric value or alphabatic value

```
 public boolean isAlpha(String name) {
    return name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");
}
```

Comment: The problem still persists. I simple cannot enter any text. Converting the unit is a later thing. I have posted my logcat if that helps.

Comment: @ChiranjeevJain i have update the answer read doc and change the code if it works or not tell be in both cases.Thanks.

Comment: That worked out well. Thanks for the help. But do you know of a way I can implement this in an EditText.? I am actually working on a Number converter app (Binary, Octal, Hex and Decimal). I am having multiple EditTexts in it. And I want user to enter any number and get others. I hope you understand my question.